# Projeto Maven muti-módulo, como controlar quais artefatos o GitLab-CI deve fazer o deploy?

Tags: maven, gitlab

Tenho um projeto Maven multi-módulo no GitLab. A estrutura é mais ou menos a seguinte:

```
/pom.xml                                          --> reator
/cooker/
/cooker/pom.xml                                   --> biblioteca principal
/security-clean/
/secutiry-clean/pom.xml                           --> dependência opcional de cooker
/samples/
/samples/pom.xml                                  --> reator dos projetos de exemplo
/samples/samples-cooker-cli-no-security/
/samples/samples-cooker-cli-no-security/pom.xml   --> exemplo sem o security
/samples/samples-cooker-cli-security/
/samples/samples-cooker-cli-security/pom.xml      --> exemplo sem o security
/samples/samples-cooker-spring-boot/
/samples/samples-cooker-spring-boot/pom.xml       --> exemplo rodando com o spring-boot
```

O `pom.xml` do reator principal consiste apenas da inserção de módulos (grupo, artefato, versão foram colocados dados artificialmente):

```xml
<module>cooker</module>
<module>security-clean</module>
<module>samples</module>
```

O reator de `samples` menciona os exemplos, mas o foco dele é ajudar a fazer a compilação/teste automatizado que eu preciso, não é o foco da questão.

No `.gitlab-ci.yml`, tenho 2 jobs em momentos distintos:

```
build:
  stage: build-test
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean test -am -pl :samples-cooker-cli-no-security,:samples-cooker-cli-security

archive:
  stage: archive
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS -DskipTests clean deploy -am -pl :cooker,:security-clean
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "target/*.jar"
    expire_in: 1 week
    when: on_success
  dependencies:
    - build
  only:
    - tags
```

Até aí, tudo tranquilo. Porém, a expectativa de alterações no `secutiry-clean` é **zero**: é um artefato do tipo `pom` que consiste da dependência de um projeto legado, porém com a remoção de toda dependência transitiva (esse projeto legado foi muito mal modelado, se faz necessário ter uma dependência "limpa").

Porém, como devo fazer no GitLab-CI para evitar reenviar o `security-clean`? E na eventual necessidade de se fazer alguma manutenção não programada no `security-clean`, como indicar que se deve fazer enviar desse artefato?

Comment: Gostaria de saber como posso melhorar minha questão, já que ela não se mostrou digna de ser fechada. Ficaria muito grato com o feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta colocar o plugin [`exists`](https://github.com/chonton/exists-maven-plugin).

Quando iniciei minha busca para isso, minha primeira ideia seria resolver isso através de shell script mesmo. Pegaria a versão através do [`help:evaluate`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545363/4438007), colocaria em uma variável e daria um jeito de saber se já existia no servidor.

Como fazer isso? Bem, aí entra a complicação... Mas, a priori, sabendo que o meu servidor de artefatos fica em um nome fixo (chamemo-lo de `http://artifactory`), poderia verificar se o artefato se encontrava lá:

```bsh
curl http://artifactory/libs-release/group/id/artifatic-id/M.m.i/
#    \________________/ \__________/ \______/ \__________/ \___/
#             |              |            |        |         |
#             |      nome do repositório  |  meu artifactId  |
#             |                           |                  |
#    autoridade do servidor            meu groupId     minha versão em questão
```

Um retorno mal sucedido (no `artifactory`, pelo menos), quando não existe essa versão do artefato, se dá com um código 404 e a seguinte saída:

```js
{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 404,
    "message" : "{\"error\":\"children items not found on all virtual repos\"}"
  } ]
}
```

Já um bem sucedido, além do código 200, uma página com os links para baixar o `pom` e o artefato gerado:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
<head><title>Index of libs-release/group/id/artifatic-id/M.m.i</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Index of libs-release/group/id/artifatic-id/M.m.i</h1>
<pre>Name                     Last modified      Size</pre><hr/>
<pre><a href="../">../</a>
<a href="artifatic-id-M.m.i.jar">artifatic-id-M.m.i.jar</a>   10-Jul-2019 20:59  25.82 KB
<a href="artifatic-id-M.m.i.pom">artifatic-id-M.m.i.pom</a>   25-Jul-2019 17:28  5.97 KB
</pre>
<hr/><address style="font-size:small;">Artifactory/6.3.0 Server at artifactory Port 80</address></body></html>
```

Mas de toda sorte eu teria de me preocupar em resgatar quais os repositórios que servem dependências existem via `help:evaluate`. O fato de possivelmente conter herança de `pom` deixa complicado tentar resolver isso via `grep` ou outras ferramentas de análise textual simples agnósticas de Maven.

Enquanto pesquisava uma maneira de fazer a listagem dos repositórios, me deparei com o plugin `org.honton.chas:exists-maven-plugin`. Seu uso é bem simples: configura se ele deve ser usado com o *goal* `local` ou `remote`  e manda executar. No caso, simulei o seguinte em um projeto de brinquedo para evitar recolocar o meu artefato (que está `SNAPSHOT`) no repositório local:

- Configuração do plugin:

```xml
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- outros plugins -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.honton.chas</groupId>
                <artifactId>exists-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>local</goal>
                            <!-- para repositórios remotos, mude o goal para
                            <goal>remote</goal>
                            -->
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!-- outros plugins -->
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.honton.chas</groupId>
                <artifactId>exists-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <!-- outras opções de build -->
</build>
```

E rodei o seguinte comando:

> Note que, como estou brincando com um artefato `SNAPSHOT`, precisei desligar a configuração `exists.skipIfSnapshot` com a opção `-Dexists.skipIfSnapshot=false`

```bsh
$ mvn -pl :artifact-id install -Dexists.skipIfSnapshot=false
```

Quando executo isso limpo, ele segue a instalação normalmente:

```bsh
$ mvn -pl :artifact-id install -Dexists.skipIfSnapshot=false

....

[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ artifact-id ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exists-maven-plugin:0.1.0:local (default) @ artifact-id ---
[INFO] group.id:artifact-id:M.m.i-SNAPSHOT does not exist
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ artifact-id ---
[INFO] Installing ...
```

Quando executo novamente:

```bsh
$ mvn -pl :artifact-id install -Dexists.skipIfSnapshot=false

....

[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ artifact-id ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- exists-maven-plugin:0.1.0:local (default) @ artifact-id ---
[INFO] setting maven.install.skip=true
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ artifact-id ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact installation
```

Isso também se aplica a projetos dentro de um reator, conforme o exemplo acima demonstra.

É importante ressaltar que, para usar o `exists-maven-plugin`, é necessário rodar com a versão do Maven pelo menos 3.5.0. Rodar em versões anteriores tem um resultado *muito* estranho. Se você simplesmente perguntar se o artefato existe (por exemplo, chamando o mojo `org.honton.chas:exists`) e apenas isso, tudo funciona bem. Porém, ao colocar para rodar junto de `install`, um grande *stacktrace*  é impresso, sem maiores dicas.

> Vejo [isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/421296/64969) se usa o `maven-wrapper`